# Compare Subquery to list of elements

Tags: mysql

I want to select all posts that match a list of tag Id's. I tried the following:

`SELECT * FROM posts as t WHERE (SELECT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE post_tags.post_id = t.id) = ALL (8, 1)`

This gives the following error:

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '8, 1))'
```

I would be glad if someone knows how to solve this.

Comment: ALL (8, 1) ?what is this ? what about LIMIT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*  
  FROM posts p
  JOIN post_tags pt 
    ON pt.post_id = p.id 
 WHERE tag_id IN(1,8) 
 GROUP 
    BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

(where '2' is equal to the number of items in IN()).